# Фиктивное поле, состоящее из нескольких полей

Tags: mariadb, sql

Есть база данных в MariaDB. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при запросе к некоторому полю *field*, которого на самом деле нет в таблице, возвращалась сумма нескольких других полей?

Все поля - как те, которые надо суммировать, так и то, которое надо имитировать - текстовые, так что под суммой понимается скорее конкатенация.

Можно было бы, конечно, сделать хранимую процедуру, но тогда нельзя будет обращаться к такому "полю" в других запросах в БД.

Хотелось бы иметь решение, которое создаёт полную иллюзию существования этого поля снаружи БД при его отсутствии на самом деле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю Вам поможет [VIEW](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp).

Comment: Можно, но это потребует "отображать" (дублировать) все остальные столбцы таблицы. И соответственно, поддерживать изменения в будущем, а это уже неприятно.
Нету ли более простого решения?

Comment: Зачем дублировать и отображать?

Comment: Ну, VIEW же создаётся как фиктивная таблица, получающая данные из других таблиц?
То есть помимо полей, из-за которых заваривается каша, придётся создавать во VIEW и остальные поля исходной таблицы.

Comment: Ну, придётся тут не то слово. Можете не создавать все поля, только нужные. Можете создать просто поля и примари ключь, а юзать через джоин таблицы и вью, если оно не всегда нужно. Но я не понимаю Вашей логики. Нужны только два поля, другие поля не нужны но сама таблица нужны...

Comment: @shau-kote используйте представления, как рекомендует @Чад. Это наиболее правильный выход. Перечисляете в нём все нужные вам столбцы плюс "фиктивный столбец".

И вообще возьмите за правило: выбирать из таблиц &nbsp; зло. Правильнее создать представление, пусть даже оно будет содержать `select * from mytable1;`.